# Input variable name: Error when using multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

My original (working) code is:

```
var input = $('input[name=todo1]').val();
```

But the problem occurs when I want go to through multiple todo fields (todo1...5). I just have no idea why:

```
var i=1;
var input = $('input[name=todo'+i+']').val();
```

gives me an error => *$("input[name=todo" + i + "]").val is not a function*

Any ideas where my thinking is going in the wrong direction or how to do this the correct way?

Comment: Your code looks correct to me! Did you paste the same exact code thats causing the error?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/edudod/1/edit — You appear to have created a reduced test case that does not include your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs just fine : http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/WyZyL/ The two snippets are equivalent:

```
var input = $('input[name=todo1]').val();
// OR: 
var i=1;
var input = $('input[name=todo'+i+']').val();
```

The reason why either would fail is if `$('input[name=todo1]')` selects an input where val is an invalid function.

Comment: It wouldn't fail in the way described in the question though.

Comment: @Quentin made it more explicit

Comment: Ah, I had it within an function and tried passing in the i for whatever wrong reasons. Thanks so much!